# FOSFacebookBundle breaks "remember me" of FOSUserBundle

Tags: facebook, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

**Problem:**

We have been using the FOSUserBundle for Symfony2, and all works fine, including the "remember me".

We recently introduced FOSFacebookBundle. Since then the "remember me" for "normal" login is broken.

**For example:**

When we use ONLY FosUSer if a user logs in via the login-form, and stays, for exemple 5 hours without activity, after clicking any link all continues to work, with the user logined and identified.

When we activate the FosFacebook, the same user also logs in via the login-form (not from facebook) and stays a time without activity. After clicking any link, he is redirected to the login form and after having entered its password again, the is redirected again to the target URL.

If we deactivate the FosFacebook from the config, the "remember me" for the FosUser works again correctly.

**Question:**

Is it normal that FosFacebook breaks the FosUser "natural" remember me for users not using FB?

If should work properly... can anyone see if we've done mistakes in our config files?

**Config Files:**

config.yml

```
# FOS User
fos_user:
    db_driver: %database_method% # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Common\ODMBundle\Document\User
    from_email:
        address:        %fos_email_address%
        sender_name:    %fos_sender_name%
    profile:
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]
    change_password:
        form:
            type:               fos_user_change_password
            handler:            fos_user.change_password.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_change_password_form
            validation_groups:  [ChangePassword]
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
            template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
        form:
            type:               fos_user_registration
            handler:            fos_user.registration.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration]
    resetting:
        token_ttl: 600
        email:
            template:   FOSUserBundle:Resetting:email.txt.twig
        form:
            type:               fos_user_resetting
            handler:            fos_user.resetting.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_resetting_form
            validation_groups:  [ResetPassword]

# FOS facebook
fos_facebook:
    file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
    alias:  facebook
    app_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    cookie: true
    permissions: [email, user_birthday]
```

security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user

    factories:
          - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            fos_facebook:
                check_path: /login_checkFB
                default_target_path: /user/
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                default_target_path: /user/
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            switch_user:  true
            remember_me:
                key:      aSecretKey
                lifetime: 604800
                path:     /
                domain:   ~

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/.*$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/private/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/user/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Comment: Xavi Montero, @kristof-van-cauwenbergh guys thanks for the question and for the answer, I had the same problem but didn't even think it can be caused by Facebook bundle

Answer (score 6):

After adding the facebooklogin, your remember me starts using the Facebookprovider to check the logincredentials. You can add a user_provider to the remember me config like this:

```
remember_me:
    key:      aSecretKey
    lifetime: 604800
    path:     /
    domain:   ~
    user_provider: fos_userbundle
```

Adding this will fix your problem.